# numpy - get minimum out of 2 maximum 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this problem, i have 2 3D arrys in numpy where i take fields/value out of it and then find the maximum of each 3D ararys, when i know this arrays i want now to find the minimum of this 2 numpy arrays but its make no sens enymore and i don't get what i want see my code below

```
np_array = np.array([ [ [
    1, 150, 300, 575, 400
    ], [
    2, 150, 145, 300, 289
    ], [
    4, 150, 275, 378, 421
    ], [
    5, 150, 225, 351, 985
    ] ], [ [
    1, 250, 400, 465, 342
    ], [
    2, 250, 245, 355, 198
    ], [
    4, 250, 375, 486, 267
    ], [
    5, 250, 325, 458, 545
    ] ]
])

print(np_array)

pricegroup_id = np_array[...,[0]]

min_dkk = np_array[...,[1]]
min_procent = np_array[...,[2]]
min_max_value = np.maximum(min_dkk, min_procent)

max_dkk = np_array[...,[3]]
max_procent = np_array[...,[4]]
max_max_value = np.maximum(max_dkk, max_procent)

min_value = np.minimum(max_max_value[...,[0]], min_max_value[...,[0]])
```

Output: np_array (OK)

```
[[[  1 150 300 575 400]
  [  2 150 145 300 289]
  [  4 150 275 378 421]
  [  5 150 225 351 985]]

 [[  1 250 400 465 342]
  [  2 250 245 355 198]
  [  4 250 375 486 267]
  [  5 250 325 458 545]]]
```

Output: min_dkk (OK)

```
[[[150]
  [150]
  [150]
  [150]]

 [[250]
  [250]
  [250]
  [250]]]
```

Output: min_procent (OK)

```
[[[300]
  [145]
  [275]
  [225]]

 [[400]
  [245]
  [375]
  [325]]]
```

Output: min_max_value (OK)

```
[[[300]
  [150]
  [275]
  [225]]

 [[400]
  [250]
  [375]
  [325]]]
```

Output: max_dkk (OK)

```
[[[575]
  [300]
  [378]
  [351]]

 [[465]
  [355]
  [486]
  [458]]]
```

Output: max_procent (OK)

```
[[[400]
  [289]
  [421]
  [985]]

 [[342]
  [198]
  [267]
  [545]]]
```

Output: max_max_value (OK)

```
[[[575]
  [300]
  [421]
  [985]]

 [[465]
  [355]
  [486]
  [545]]]
```

Output: pricegroup_id (OK)

```
[[[1]
  [2]
  [4]
  [5]]

 [[1]
  [2]
  [4]
  [5]]]
```

Output: min_value (WRONG)

```
[[[300]
  [150]
  [275]
  [225]]

 [[400]
  [250]
  [375]
  [325]]]
```

So now is the question how do i wrong and why its taking the min. of all values and not only on the array level i want?

**The resualt i search is this:**

```
[[[400]
  [289]
  [421]
  [985]]

 [[342]
  [198]
  [267]
  [545]]]
```

Comment: Instead of cluttering the question with outputs that are "correct", you should rather describe, what each step is supposed to do. We don't know this and we can't guess from your code. At the moment, all outputs are "correct", meaning, the program executed your instructions properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are expecting the result you say you are. Your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to and the result you expect doesn't contain any of the input values. The mininum of

```
array([[[300],
        [150],
        [275],
        [225]],
       [[400],
        [250],
        [375],
        [325]]])
```

and

```
array([[[575],
        [300],
        [421],
        [985]],
       [[465],
        [355],
        [486],
        [545]]])
```

is

```
array([[[300],
        [150],
        [275],
        [225]],
       [[400],
        [250],
        [375],
        [325]]])
```

Comment: This is not an answer, rather a comment.

Comment: I tried to comment but it wouldn't fit. Feel free to delete it. I can answer when he/she explains what is actually the problem. Surely "nothing is wrong" is an answer?

Comment: If you trying to run my code, you can se the expected min. values not is what i want its shut ending out of the last data output, and its do not, and ofc its doing what i tell it, but then i tell it wrong :) the problem is i get the wrong min. data output value.

Comment: Which 2 arrays do you want the mininum of?

Comment: min_max_value and max_max_value

Comment: The min. of those two arrays is what I've stated in my answer, which is what you are getting, isn't it? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: what your are misunderstanding is i get right now this value [[[300]
  [150]
  [275]
  [225]]

 [[400]
  [250]
  [375]
  [325]]] and what i want is [[[400]
  [289]
  [421]
  [985]]

 [[342]
  [198]
  [267]
  [545]]] so its not returning the right min. data i want

Comment: But those values aren't in min_max_value or max_max_value, they are in max_procent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165036/discussion-between-parisnakitakejser-and-stev).